# Why are there Unicode and ANSI versions of the CreateAcceleratorTable and TranslateAccelerator functions?

Tags: winapi

As far as I can see neither the [CreateAcceleratorTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646365(v=vs.85).aspx) function nor the [TranslateAccelerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646373(v=vs.85).aspx) functions handle string or character data so I'm wondering why they come in both Unicode and ANSI versions? This is the [ACCEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646340(v=vs.85).aspx) data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CreateAcceleratorTable` does handle character data.

According to the [MSDN documentation of `ACCEL` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646340(v=vs.85).aspx)

> **key**
>   Type: **WORD**
>
> The accelerator key. This member can be either a virtual-key code or a character code.

A character code can be more than just a ASCII char. Out of the ASCII range, its meaning depends on whether it is ANSI or Unicode.

Why would a character code be more than ASCII? Isn't our keyboard only has ASCII characters anyway? Well, here is my guessing. Imagine that on Japanese Windows where ANSI defaults to Shift-JIS, a Japan user that uses Kana Input (where a keystroke can directly type out あ/い/う/え...) press an accelerator key of those Kana, like `Ctrl+あ`.

As for the `TranslateAccelerator`, since that an accelerator can be non-ASCII, there is a need too, to translate the key code of `WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_SYSKEYDOWN`, `WM_CHAR`, and `WM_SYSCHAR`, to Unicode before passing to the internal implementation.

The following code are excerpt from the leaked Windows 2000 source code.

Unicode version:

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
case WM_CHAR:
case WM_SYSCHAR:
    return NtUserTranslateAccelerator(hwnd, hAccel, lpMsg);
```

ANSI version:

```
WPARAM wParamT;
// irrelevant code here...
case WM_KEYDOWN:
case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
case WM_CHAR:
case WM_SYSCHAR:
    wParamT = lpMsg->wParam;
    RtlMBMessageWParamCharToWCS(lpMsg->message, &(lpMsg->wParam));
    iT = NtUserTranslateAccelerator(hwnd, hAccel, lpMsg);
    lpMsg->wParam = wParamT;
    return iT;
```

Source code of `RtlMBMessageWParamCharToWCS` can be [found here](http://read.pudn.com/downloads3/sourcecode/windows/248345/win2k/private/ntos/w32/ntuser/rtl/chartran.c__.htm).